# Error when viewing Members section in Umbraco

Tags: active-directory, umbraco, umbraco7, notsupportedexception, activedirectorymembership

Using Umbraco 7.12.4

I'm using an instance of AD LDS to authenticate backoffice users and members (both authenticate using the exact same AD LDS instance).

In Web.config:

```
<providers>
<add name="BackofficeMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="userPrincipalName" connectionUsername="username@example.com" connectionPassword="password" connectionProtection="None" />
<add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.UsersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
<add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="userPrincipalName" connectionUsername="username@example.com" connectionPassword="password" enableSearchMethods="true" connectionProtection="None"/>
</providers>
```

I get the following error when I navigate to the Members section in the backoffice:

`System.NotSupportedException: The property 'LastActivityDate' is not supported by the Active Directory membership provider.`

I have not been able to determine what's going on. My best guess at this point is that it has to do with using AD LDS instead of full AD? The error makes it sound like AD LDS doesn't support that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much that I think. Have you had a look at the AD/OAuth extensions for Umbraco? Maybe they would help:

https://github.com/Shazwazza/UmbracoIdentity - is for front end users

https://github.com/umbraco/UmbracoIdentityExtensions - is for the back office

I've not tried using both at the same time, usually it's either the front end OR back end users I've had to authenticate via AD/OAuth.